# Can't activate NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: swift, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to set up UI for ViewController through NSLayoutConstraint. Here's the code I'm using:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    private var profileUser = katyPerry
    
    private var profileImage: UIImageView {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: profileUser.login))
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //profileUser = users.randomElement() ?? User(login: "default", name: "default")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpView()
    }
    
    func setUpView() {
        view.addSubview(profileImage)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            profileImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            profileImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            profileImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        ])
    }
}
```

When running the app, it throws an Error when accessing the view. Xcode highlight .activate and gives following description: ***Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)***.

How to fix this?

Comment: Every time you say `profileImage` you are creating a new image view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every time you say `profileImage` you are creating a new image view. So you are talking about five different image views in just one little piece of code:

```
view.addSubview(profileImage) // image view 1
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    profileImage.leadingAnchor..., // image view 2
    profileImage.topAnchor..., // image view 3
// ... and so on
```

To fix the problem, change

```
private var profileImage: UIImageView {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: profileUser.login))
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}
```

To

```
private lazy var profileImage: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: profileUser.login))
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between this and what you had?

Comment: Yep. The solution you provided works only once profileImage is accessed for the very first time. (because of it being lazy). Do we always add "()" when making lazy variables?

Comment: You don't quite have the idea. The `= {...}()` notation is completely different from the `lazy` designation. We need the `= {...}()` because we want to initialize our property by _running_ `()` a _function_ `{}`. We need `lazy` in order to make it legal to refer to another property in the initialization function.

Comment: Once again thank you for your answer and explanation! :)